# NullReferenceException in VS2013 when breakpoints hit in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, nullreferenceexception

After updating Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio to the latest stable version, I get a strange error. When launching the application in debug mode, Visual Studio will sometimes throw a NullReferenceException where it is not expected. This happens at the line

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => ContinueOnCreate());
```

in my Activity's OnCreate method. The strange thing, though, is that when placing a breakpoint on the *previous* line, I immediately get

```
Unhandled Exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

in Visual Studio once the breakpoint is hit. The line in question in this case is a simple method call to an instance method:

```
AnimateWidgets();
```

...and if I also place breakpoint on the first curly-brace inside this method, the breakpoint will not get hit due to the NullReferenceException being thrown when AnimateWidgets is called.

If I place a breakpoint on the first curly-brace of the OnCreate method of the activity it gets hit as expected, but when stepping through the method I get a similar NullReferenceException once the method call to CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie is made at

```
CookieSyncManager.CreateInstance(this);
CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
CookieSyncManager.Instance.Sync();
```

I am guessing this is a bug in Xamarin, but I was wondering if anyone has had a similar experience. I am using Xamarin version 3.9.547.0 and Xamarin.Android version 4.20.2.1.

[**Edit**: This issue is caused when the CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie method is called].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by an issue in an updated version of Android WebView, likely caused by incorrect forwarding of signals to a SIGSEGV signal handler. It only occurs in Debug builds, not Release.

A temporary workaround is to downgrade WebView on the device by going "Settings" -> "Apps" - > "Android System WebView" -> "Uninstall updates". Using version 39 works, but it might also work with later versions.

For more information, see

http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=5919

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29365

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476831

Many thanks to Jon Goldberger at Xamarin for promptly tracking down this issue.

[**Edit**: [Jonathan Pryor has a workaround that doesn't require downgrading the WebView](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29365#c4). I have been unable to resolve the issue with this fix, but your mileage may vary. Also thanks to Jon Goldberger for this link].

Answer (score 0):

Remove the runtime in the android phone.

I solved the same situation in low API version phone.
This problem happened when I use multi-thread or async method in old API level phone.